# Why I am not getting any error in below code?

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

Below is my code.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public String publicMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is Public Method");
        return "This is Public Method";
    }

    abstract  public String abstractMethod();
}



public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{

    @Override
    public String abstractMethod() {
        String str = "This is abstract method implementtation in ConcreteClass";
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }

    public String abstractMethod(String string) {
        String str = "This is overloaded method abstractMethod in ConcreteClass";
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }

    public String publicMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is Public Method in ConcreteClass");
        return "This is Public Method in ConcreteClass";
    }

}
```

So I have `public String publicMethod()` method in abtract class as well as in class extending that abstract class. Also I have not given `@Override` annotation. Why no error given ? Also is this method overriding  or `publicMethod` is getting ignored ?

Comment: `@Override` is not required, it's still being overriden.

Comment: The second method is overloaded not overridden, since the argument makes it having a different signature.

Comment: In Java `@Override` has two purposes: 1)  self-document which methods belong to the parent class 2) Ensure that you avoid errors (e.g. you *think* that method is of a parent class/can be overridden but you are mistaken) however both of these are just about "user friendliness" and not required for the compiler. In other languages (e.g. Kotlin) overriding must always be declared.

Comment: @Harshal Maybe some people think that your question is basic and you were lazy to not lookup the documentation before asking. Some SO users expect you to "do your homework" before asking a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Override` is an optional annotation. If you are using this annotation for a method that doesn't override a super-class method and doesn't implement an interface method, the compiler gives an error.

However, it is allowed to override a method without marking it with that annotation (though using that annotation is useful, since it can catch errors when you intend to override a method but get the signature of the method you intend to override wrong).

Yes, your sub-class's `publicMethod()` overrides the super-class method of the same name.

Comment: More information on this annotation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting from the documentation written in oracle's [site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html&ved=2ahUKEwiIhveAq7LkAhUKK48KHUvnCf0QFjACegQIDxAI&usg=AOvVaw2mbNbS6pWaGyk-ftZixbZG):

> @Override annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass. Overriding methods will be discussed in Interfaces and Inheritance. While it is not required to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors.

That's why you're not getting any error. It's optional but recommended. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you need to use the override notation and also there is no error in the program you can see the complete working of the program if you add a main class. Like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public String publicMethod ()
      {
        System.out.println ("This is Public Method");
        return "This is Public Method";
      }
      abstract public String abstractMethod ();
    }

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
    {
      @Override public String abstractMethod ()
      {
        String str = "This is abstract method implementtation in ConcreteClass";
          System.out.println (str);
          return str;
      }

      public String abstractMethod (String string)
      {
        String str = "This is overloaded method abstractMethod in ConcreteClass";
        System.out.println (str);
        return str;
      }
      public String publicMethod ()
      {
        System.out.println ("This is Public Method in ConcreteClass");
        return "This is Public Method in ConcreteClass";
      }
    }

public class Main
    {
      public static void main (String[]args)
      {
        ConcreteClass c = new ConcreteClass ();
          c.abstractMethod ();
          c.publicMethod ();
      }

    }
```

And this gives the output  as :
This is abstract method implementtation in ConcreteClass
This is Public Method in ConcreteClass
 AND IF YOU WANT TO CALL THE ABSTRACT CLASS PUBLICMETHOD THEN YOU CAN use the super keyword in the ConcreteClass 's  public method.